# Django how to count 10 most occurrences

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this model:

```
class Liker(models.Model):
    pic = models.IntegerField()
    pic_owners = models.IntegerField()
```

I am wondering what is the most efficient queryset to find top 10 pic_owners, i.e. the pic_owners whose pics have been liked the most?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count
rating = Liker.objects.values('pic_owners') \
                      .annotate(Count('pic_owners')) \
                      .order_by('-pic_owners__count')[:10]
```

This query will return a list of dicts with two keys: 'pic_owners' and 'pic_owners__count'.